# Check if file was created in a loop, if not, create again on next iteration

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I put together a short bash script using `fswebcam` to take photos for a timelapse using a USB webcam and a RPi and to name the files sequentially with a bunch of leading zeros.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
while [ $counter -lt 999999 ]; do
    number=$(printf "%07d" "$counter")
    sudo fswebcam -r 1920x1080 --no-banner ./$number.jpg
    let counter=counter+1
    sleep 30
done
```

Every once in a while (happened 3 times during 86,000+ iterations) it would fail to write the file to disk, for whatever reason, effectively breaking the sequence.

How can I improve the code to check if the file with the last iteration number was indeed created, and if not, attempt to create it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the previous file exist or not:

some logic like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
while [ $counter -lt 999999 ]; do
    number=$(printf "%07d" "$counter")        
    let pre_counter=counter-1
    pre_numer=$(printf "%07d" "$pre_counter")  
    if [ ! -f ./$pre_numer.jpg ]; then
       sudo fswebcam -r 1920x1080 --no-banner ./$pre_numer.jpg
    else
        sudo fswebcam -r 1920x1080 --no-banner ./$number.jpg
        let counter=counter+1
    fi;
    sleep 30
done
```

**Note: i haven't tested this**

Edit: Fixed spacing that was causing a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Add after the: 
`sudo fswebcam -r 1920x1080 --no-banner ./$number.jpg`:

the code:

```
if [ $? != 0 ] || ! [ -f ./$number.jpg ];then
 sudo fswebcam -r 1920x1080 --no-banner ./$number.jpg
 sleep 30
fi
```

This should retry once more the command if previous command fails/doesn't create the file.

Comment: Something seems to be not working, I'm getting the following readout:

    Writing JPEG image to './0000000.jpg'.
    ./test.sh: line 6: [: missing `]'
    ./test.sh: line 6: !-f: command not found

Also, you seem to have forgotten the _then_ after the _if_ conditions.

Comment: Seems to run without errors now, but the check doesn't seem to work. To test, I deleted the previously saved image while it was in the sleep state and during the next iteration it did not try to recreate the same file, but rather continued increasing the number. I'm assuming I had to keep the other `sleep 30` and `let counter=counter+1` after the `fi` statement? Would that not also make it sleep for 30 seconds twice if the check did work?

Comment: Yes, you should keep the other part of the code. The `$?` tests if execution of the previous command was ok. Adding the code, it gives one more try if the fille was not created or if the previous command exited with an error. It adds only one more try. The solution in the answer skips if  the file doesn't create.